# What is the meaning of " this girdle is killing me "

Tags: phrases

[image]
The sentence of *this girdle is killing me* comes from the TV show *Growing.Pains.S01E05.Superdad*. Maggy said "Because you're not a mother", and then Jason replied this. I looked up this *girdle* in the dictionary and searched pics on Google, They all mean a tight piece of clothing worn predominantly by women, and this definition does not fit here. So what is the meaning of this sentence or phrase?

Comment: What exactly are you unsure about? You can find this meaning of "kill" in a dictionary, e.g. [sense 6a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kill). And you know what a girdle is. Can you not understand why tight clothing might cause pain? Or do you have some other concern about the dialog (why is he wearing a girdle? why are they talking about him being a mother?) In which case you need to present more context because it's not clear from what you say exactly what is going on in the sitcom.

Comment: I think this is an Off Topic *cultural / humorous* reference, not directly concerned with the English language

Comment: I mean why is he talking about girdle? Because apparently that man couldnot wear a girdle. @StuartF

Comment: So where should I post this kind of question? thank you. @FumbleFingers

Comment: Well, you've got your answer, so just leave it where it is. I don't suppose there's a Stack Exchange subsite specifically for British cultural references.

Comment: If you have the English but not the joke: *You're right I am not exactly a mother, but I'm trying to take the role. I am wearing women's underwear.* If you take it seriously that he is wearing a girdle, there is no joke left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... Back in the 70s we used to say it all the time. People said it on TV. I’m sure Eric Morecambe was always saying it. ‘Ooh, my girdle’s killing me!’ Or was that Kenneth Williams? Probably both. I can’t remember why we said it, it was just one of those advertising catchphrases that made you smile and stuck in the mind, back in the days when adverts stuck in the mind ...[source](https://www.balancemedia.co.uk/2017/07/07/word-of-the-week-gird/)

I think the character said this according to the above reason, as it was common those days, or he wanted to say something that is common among women in response to Maggy to point out mockingly that he is woman (a mother). His hands, as in the frame, was trying to do something related to being uncomfortable with the clothe, as the slogan propose, by the way.

Also, this [explanation](http://www.femulate.org/2010/06/my-girdle-is-killing-me-not.html) can help to interpret the sentence.

> "My Girdle Is Killing Me", that comes from the fact of not getting properly fitted in the right kind of girdle for your body shape and your life style, and going through some form of Girdle training.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

"My girdle's killing me!" is a line from a television advert for [Playtex](http://www.corsetiere.net/Spirella/Rubber.htm#playtex) girdles.